# Can Cypress test if a control is Pristine?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I am working on an Angular 4 app and we're using Cypress for front-end/integration testing.
On one of our forms we have a cancel button which clears all inputs on a child form and resets the form.
I am wondering is there any way for Cypress to check if the form or a control is pristine, or do I need to check that the contents of the inputs are all cleared? (I know how to do the latter, but would rather be able to check using Pristine than needing to iterate through all controls).

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
cy.get('[data-test=cancelButton]').click();
cy.get('[data-test=referenceField').should('be.empty');
cy.get('[data-test=referenceField').should('have.attr', 'placeholder', 'Numbered list number');
```

I would like to just do something like

```
cy.get('[data-test=cancelButton]').click();
cy.get('[data-test=referenceField').should('be.pristine');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress allows you to create [custom child commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Child-Commands). Here's the basic syntax:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldBePristine', {
    prevSubject: true // this allows it to be chained off another command
}, (subject /*, arg1, arg2, ...*/) => {
    // subject is whatever is wrapped by the Cypress object that
    // .shouldBePristine() is called on

    // In your case, you would do something like this:
    expect(subject).to.be.empty;
    expect(subject).to.have.attr('placeholder', 'Numbered list number');

    // This command does not need to change the subject for the next function
    // in the chain, so we will just return what was passed in
    return subject;
});
```

Then you would call your command like this:

```
cy.get('[data-test=referenceField]').shouldBePristine();
```

You could also [write a custom chai helper](http://www.chaijs.com/guide/helpers/), but that process looks to be significantly more complicated.

Comment: I think writing a custom command is the way to go, but when I try to do `subject.should(...` I get the error `cypress_runner.js:141523 TypeError: subject.should is not a function`.
Here's what `subject` is when I check it in the console.
`[input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "[data-test=createNumberListReference]"]`

Comment: @red_dorian Doh, that's my bad. `subject` is the underlying wrapped object, not the Cypress wrapper, so you would need a Chai assertion. I usually double check my answers but I forgot this time. Sorry about that! I've edited my answer. Let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's worth noting that Cypress commands cannot actually be called within custom commands. I found that out the hard way when debugging my answer just now.

Comment: it helps, and has definitely pointed me in the right direction. Checking `.empty` and the placeholder work for input fields, but isn't a general solution for multiple input types, or fields with default values. 
`expect(subject).to.have.value(subject[0].defaultValue)`works for the latter. But that's a problem with my question, not your answer.
I'm marking your answer as the solution and will work on my own function and include that as a separate post here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Much appreciated! Glad I could help.